# how to compare two images in which words are different?

Tags: opencv

I repetitively take screen shots of a web page, while I can't get the score code of the page, and want to know weather the page has changed, usually, only some words in the page will change, sometimes the whole page could be changed.

I have used opencvsharp, https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp, and histogram to compare the screen shots, but the result shows that similarity is quite high, even if there are difference of 3 words.

the code of histogram:

```
double compareFacesByHist(Mat img, Mat orgImg)
    {
        Mat tmpImg = new Mat();
        if (img.Size().Equals(orgImg.Size()) == false)
        {
            Cv2.Resize(img, tmpImg, new OpenCvSharp.Size(orgImg.Cols, orgImg.Rows));
        }
        else
        {
            tmpImg = img;
        }


        tmpImg = tmpImg.CvtColor(ColorConversionCodes.BGR2HSV);
        orgImg = orgImg.CvtColor(ColorConversionCodes.BGR2HSV);


        int hBins = 256, sBins = 256;
        int[] histSize = { hBins, sBins };

        Rangef hRanges = new Rangef(0, 180);

        Rangef sRanges = new Rangef(0, 255);

        Rangef[] ranges = { hRanges, sRanges };
        int[] channels = { 0, 1 };
        Mat hist1 = new Mat(), hist2 = new Mat();
        Cv2.CalcHist(new Mat[] { tmpImg }, channels, new Mat(), hist1, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false);
        Cv2.Normalize(hist1, hist1, 0, 1, NormTypes.MinMax, -1, new Mat());
        Cv2.CalcHist(new Mat[] { orgImg }, channels, new Mat(), hist2, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false);
        Cv2.Normalize(hist2, hist2, 0, 1, NormTypes.MinMax, -1, new Mat());

        double similarityValue = Cv2.CompareHist(hist1, hist2, HistCompMethods.Correl);// CV_COMP_CORREL);
        return similarityValue;
    }
```

some result: 
0.999999999797675
0.999999648350145

I guess the histogram is only using color information to compare two image, it is hard to reflect words changing. I would like to know some better way to compare such kind of images. thank you.

Comment: histogram wont be able to tell the difference. use OCR and compare  or minimum use cv::templatematching

Answer (score 0):

Take the pixelwise difference of the two images and do a summation (essentially a mean absolute error).
If the value you get is very close to 0 nothing changed, otherwise there is a change.

Comment: If the web browser is minimized and then restored, there are some pixels changed definitely. And I can't prevent minimizing or other windows covering the browser, so it is hard to use this way. still thank your suggestion.

Comment: This is a different problem. Your question is asking how to compare two images.

Answer (score 0):

I have used @nathancy's way, ssim, to compare the images, the result is much better than histogram.
By screen shotting a notepad to get images to compare, and the notepad contains a editing document which includes some line of sentences.

1, exact same two screen shots : 0.999999295236082

2, add a few words into the documents: 0.996387690483554

3, deleting the words just added : 0.999760811255743

I am still using the opencvsharp and the ssim method is translated from the c++ version of opencv.

```
    Scalar getMSSIM(Mat i1, Mat i2)
    {
        const double C1 = 6.5025, C2 = 58.5225;
        /***************************** INITS **********************************/
        MatType d = MatType.CV_32F;

        Mat I1 = new Mat(), I2 = new Mat();
        i1.ConvertTo(I1, d);           // cannot calculate on one byte large values
        i2.ConvertTo(I2, d);

        Mat I2_2 = I2.Mul(I2);        // I2^2
        Mat I1_2 = I1.Mul(I1);        // I1^2
        Mat I1_I2 = I1.Mul(I2);        // I1 * I2

        /***********************PRELIMINARY COMPUTING ******************************/

        Mat mu1 = new Mat(), mu2 = new Mat();   //
        Cv2.GaussianBlur(I1, mu1, new OpenCvSharp.Size(11, 11), 1.5);
        Cv2.GaussianBlur(I2, mu2, new OpenCvSharp.Size(11, 11), 1.5);

        Mat mu1_2 = mu1.Mul(mu1);
        Mat mu2_2 = mu2.Mul(mu2);
        Mat mu1_mu2 = mu1.Mul(mu2);

        Mat sigma1_2 = new Mat(), sigma2_2 = new Mat(), sigma12 = new Mat();

        Cv2.GaussianBlur(I1_2, sigma1_2, new OpenCvSharp.Size(11, 11), 1.5);
        sigma1_2 -= mu1_2;

        Cv2.GaussianBlur(I2_2, sigma2_2, new OpenCvSharp.Size(11, 11), 1.5);
        sigma2_2 -= mu2_2;

        Cv2.GaussianBlur(I1_I2, sigma12, new OpenCvSharp.Size(11, 11), 1.5);
        sigma12 -= mu1_mu2;

        ///////////////////////////////// FORMULA ////////////////////////////////
        Mat t1, t2, t3;

        t1 = 2 * mu1_mu2 + C1;
        t2 = 2 * sigma12 + C2;
        t3 = t1.Mul(t2);              // t3 = ((2*mu1_mu2 + C1).*(2*sigma12 + C2))

        t1 = mu1_2 + mu2_2 + C1;
        t2 = sigma1_2 + sigma2_2 + C2;
        t1 = t1.Mul(t2);               // t1 =((mu1_2 + mu2_2 + C1).*(sigma1_2 + sigma2_2 + C2))

        Mat ssim_map = new Mat();
        Cv2.Divide(t3, t1, ssim_map);      // ssim_map =  t3./t1;


        Scalar mssim = Cv2.Mean(ssim_map);// mssim = average of ssim map


        return mssim;
    }
```

However, I'd like to get the difference image, so that I can take a look at it. and I could check more situation to verify ssim. thanks

Comment: actually, ssim_map is the different image, which is 32F format and in -1 to 1, a little conversion could be made to let it be shown